# Cannot Delete Cells if they contain value VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that has a bunch of Cells in the A column (1500) that look like this:

> ```
> Perfect Imperfection;"Kevin Gates";"Luca Brasi 2: Gangsta Grillz";1
> ```

or

> ```
> Perfect Imperfection;"Kevin Gates";"Luca Brasi 2: Gangsta Grillz";0
> ```

I am trying to delete cells that end in `;1`

Note that some song titles have a `1` in them, and others take the form of: 
`Perfect Imperfection;;;1`

I'm using the following code from a different Stack Overflow post that I have edited slightly:

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithX()

maxRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
MsgBox (maxRow)
For i = 1 To maxRow
    Do While (StrComp(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Text, ";1", vbTextCompare) = 0)
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        MsgBox ("Deleted")
   Loop
Next

End Sub
```

If it helps, here are some examples of the file:

> ```
> Perfect Imperfection;"Kevin Gates";"Luca Brasi 2: Gangsta Grillz";1
> Perfect Strangers;"Lil Wayne";"Tha Carter V";1
> Perplexing Pegasus;"Rae Sremmurd";;1
> Phone Numbers Wiz Khalifa;;;0
> Piano Man;"Billy Joel";;1
> Picasso Baby Jay Z;;;0
> Pick Up the Phone ft Young Thug Travis Scott;;;0
> Picture;"Kid Rock";;1
> Pillowtalk  Conor Maynard;;;1
> Pimp Juice;Nelly;Nellyville;1
> Pinball Wizard;"The Who";;1
> Pink Toes  Childish Gambino;;;1
> ```

Which should look like:

> ```
> Phone Numbers Wiz Khalifa;;;0
> Picasso Baby Jay Z;;;0
> Pick Up the Phone ft Young Thug Travis Scott;;;0
> ```

However, nothing is deleting. Can anybody advise? NOTE -- this not need to be done in VBA, I just want to delete rows that end in 1

Comment: You need to loop backward while you're deleting - you're changing the collection you're iterating over when you delete.

Comment: @Comintern Do you know how I can go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Requirements:** Delete entire row of values in column 1 that end with ";1"

For this kind of requirements suggest the use of `AutoFilter` and `SpecialCells` to delete all the target rows at once.

Try this:

```
 Sub AutoFilter_To_DeleteRows()
    With ActiveSheet
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Rem Add a temporary header to avoid indiscriminate deletion of the first row.
        .Cells(1).EntireRow.Insert
        .Cells(1).Value2 = "Temporary Header"
        Rem Filter values ending with ";1"
        .Columns(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*;1"
        Rem Delete all resulting rows
        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Keeping the answer close to the code that you have written.

You need to loop from the bottom of your list to the top.  That way when rows are deleted, you do not skip rows.  This can be done in your **For** loop by starting with the bottom of the list and moving backwards to the first row using  **Step -1**.

The **Right** function can be used to test the last two characters of the cell value to see if they match to **;1**.

The **Do While** can be removed.

The **MsgBox**'s have been expanded to provide more detail when testing.  They can be commented out once you are happy with the way the code is running.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithX()

maxRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
MsgBox "No. of Rows: " & maxRow

    For i = maxRow To 1 Step -1
        ValOfCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value2
            If Right(ValOfCell, 2) = ";1" Then
                Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                MsgBox "Row: " & i & vbCrLf & "Value: " & ValOfCell & vbCrLf & "has been deleted."
            End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Jerry, I could not get *StrComp* to work the way I wanted, so I used *Mid* & *Len* to accomplish what you need. This will work since all the song titles end with ";?". Also, I did not add to the code, but consider doing everything you can to not use the *Select* method - this can lead to complications.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithX()

Dim maxrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
maxrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To maxrow
    Do While Mid(Cells(i, 1).Text, Len(Cells(i, 1).Text) - 1, 2) = ";1"
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        MsgBox ("Deleted")
   Loop
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: That throws a run-time error 5 if the cell doesn't contain at least 2 characters.

Comment: Sorry, based on the examples you had, I assumed all would be at least 2 characters in length. String functions will return errors if they are no results to return. Perhaps, throw a "On Error Resume Next" above the Do loop, then, "On Error goto 0" after the loop - this will account for strings less than 2 in length.